# CSS to simulate paper page on screen, but only show "printable area" on browser print-preview

Tags: html, printing, css, page-layout

I have managed to create an HTML page layout that emulates a paper document page, with a white paper page casting a shadow over a gray background, pretty similar to Acrobat Reader, MS Word and even Firefox's very own Print Preview visualization.

I followed a lot of suggestions found in SO about proper use of CSS3 (in which I am a total beginner), and the last feature were the @media rules.

So, I got to the present document, where the browser's print preview should display only the "printable_area" div and its content, but print preview is showing blank, and I don't know that I am doing wrong (I am using Firefox):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>A Page to Print</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media print {
            html, body, .paperpage {display:none}
            .printable_area * {display:block}
            }

            @media all {
            html, body {
                margin:0; padding:0; height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #aaa;
            }

            .paperpage {
                position: absolute;
                width: 600px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin-left: -320px;
                left: 50%;
                top:10px;
                bottom:10px;
                background-color: white;
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .printable_area {
                position: relative;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: auto !important;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            #cabecalho {
                padding: 0;
                height: 100px;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width:1px;
                border-color:black;                
            }

            #main {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            h3 {
                text-align: center
            }

            #rodape {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:50%;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
                background-color: hsl(185,60%,90%);
                text-align: center;
            }}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="paperpage">
        <div class="printable_area">
            <div id="cabecalho" style=" background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4DCDD6 0%, #fff 50%);"/>
                <img src="MarcaMiotecNova.svg" height="40%" />
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <h3>Eletromiografia de Superfície</h3>
                <p align="center">Exame realizado em condições ideais de temperatura e eletrovoltagem.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rodape">
                <p>My Company</p>
                <p>Address St, 1234 - Don't Drive - Nice City</p>
                <p><a href="http://www.mycompany.com.br">www.mycompany.com.br</a></p>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the double-closing-brace (`}}`) a typo, or present in your real CSS?

Comment: @David: Those are the closing braces of `#rodape` and `@media all`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, ah! Of course... =S

Answer (score 5):

An element will not be rendered if it, or any of its ancestors, is `display: none`.

You have set `html` to `display: none` so no element in the document will be rendered.

You need to be more selective about the content you hide.

Comment: that's exactely the problem: the very goal I am trying to achieve is to render the content and hide the container (parent) at the same time. A possible alternative would be to have a transparent master container (body) and two "layered" siblings inside it: page_content and paper_page. Would it be possible, to draw things one "over" another (as opposed to "one inside the other")? Thanks for reading!